# How can I view the definition of a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I make a temporary table in SQL Server:

```
create  table #stun (name varchar(40),id int,gender varchar(40))
```

How can I view its definition afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

you can check this way-

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM table_name  -- any table from database

EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#TempTable'

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**
You can query data against it within the current session :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #yourtemporarytable;
```

Sometimes, you may want to create a temporary table that is accessible across connections. In this case, you can use global temporary tables.

Unlike a temporary table, the name of a global temporary table starts with a double hash symbol (##).

```
CREATE TABLE ##global_temp (
    ...
);
 SELECT
   *
FROM 
    ##global_temp
```

**Solution 2 :**
Using SSMS, you can find the table in the left pane >> Design >> get the table structure.